# Howto configure kafkaConnect from kafka to cassandra

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to setup the kafka connect from kafka topic to cassandra

The problem is simple: saying I have a demo topic in kafka with json data like

```
{"id":"1", "name":"Alex", "clicks":2}
```

I would like automatically to push it into the cassanra table with columns id, name, clicks.

I'm looking into [kafka-connect-cassandra](https://github.com/tuplejump/kafka-connect-cassandra), but the only example I can find is to reading from cassandra and writing to another cassandra table via kafka in the middle.

My question is how can I make it read from kafka and not cassandra?
I'm looking for some connector open source with example for doing that.

Comment: How you connected kafka to the cassandra database ?
i was  following this but didn't get any success .
http://itechseeker.com/en/tutorials-2/apache-cassandra/connecting-kafka-to-cassandra-sink/

Answer (score 1):

The example you are referring to is showcasing both source and sink features of connector together. If your use-case is to push data from Kafka topic to a Cassandra table then all you need is a sink. Follow these steps

1. Create your own sink properties file. Use [this as an](https://github.com/tuplejump/kafka-connect-cassandra/blob/master/examples/config/sink.properties) example. Save it as `my-sink.properties`
2. Go to the home directory of installation and execute the command `CLASSPATH=<<path-to-connector-jar>> ./bin/connect-standalone connect-standalone.properties my-sink.properties`

If you are interested in example of more detailed steps, see here:https://github.com/yaravind/kafka-connect-jenkins#standalone-mode (Full disclosure: I maintain that connector for Jenkins.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and I followed what's on https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-cassandra-sink-the-perfect-match/. I'm using the DataMountaineer driver (http://docs.datamountaineer.com/en/latest/cassandra-sink.html), and setting it up in distributed mode.

Once you have it set, your configuration Json for the cassandra connector (uploaded via REST API for confluent-connect) should look something like:

```
{
"name": "cassandra.sink.yourConfigName",
"config": {
    "connector.class": "com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "<your topic>",
    "connect.cassandra.sink.kcql": "INSERT INTO <your_table> SELECT *  FROM <your_kafka_topic>;",
    "connect.cassandra.contact.points": "<cassandra nodes>",
    "connect.cassandra.port": "<cassandra port>",
    "connect.cassandra.key.space": "<cassandra keyspace>",
    "connect.cassandra.username": "cassandra",
    "connect.cassandra.password": "cassandra"
    }}
```